# Input using stdin in C/C++

Tags: c

I have to read graph inputs (all at once) (an example below):

```
6 8 //no of vertices, edges
0 1 2 //connectivity from vertex 0 to vertex 1, with weight 2
0 2 1
0 4 2
1 2 4
2 3 5
3 4 5
4 1 2
4 5 5
```

What is the best way to read inputs dynamically. I have to read all the above content at once. I need to read it dynamically since the number of edges and vertices can change, with a maximun of 10000. 
The following doesn't work:

```
int *twod_array; 
int N,M; //no of vertices, edges
scanf("%d %d", &N, &M);
twod_array = (int *)malloc(sizeof(int)*N*M); //where N = no of rows, M = no of cols
for(i=0; i < N; i++) {
  for(j=0; j < M; j++) {
scanf("%d",&twod_array[i*M +j]);
  }
}
for(i=0; i < N; i++) {
  for(j=0; j < M; j++) {
    if(twod_array[i*M +j] == "\0") {
twod_array[i*M +j] = 0;
    }
  }
}
```

Also, is this the best way for graphs in C/C++ or is it better to use struct, since traversals will be done.

Comment: The following doen't work because (at least) 1. `&N&M` is invalid. it should be `&N,&M` 2. `2d_array` is invalid as identifier since it cannot start with a number. 3. `where N = no of rows, M = no of cols` makes no sense as code. make it a comment. 4. `N` won't affect the number of rows nor cols. 5. `M` is number of rows, not cols. 6. the asssignment `2d_array[i*M +j] = "\0"` make no sence. it should be comparation to `'\0'` or just nothing.

Comment: @MikeCAT - made the necessary changes. Still doesn't work as needed.

Comment: Also `if(twod_array[i*M +j] = "\0")` dosent compare...should be `==`.

Comment: @amdixon - I am currently using C

Comment: So remove the tag c++ for confusion...

Comment: @SachinS 1. The proglem of no. of rows and cols isn't corrected. 2. The comparation between integer and the pointer `twod_array[i*M +j] == "\0"` makes no sense. What do you want to do by it?

Comment: When stymied, try something simpler. Try reading *one* column of variable length; once that works perfectly, you can think about three. (Also, if you are using C, you must refrain from C++ style comments.)

Comment: "is this the best way for graphs in C/C++" - they are different languages. Pick one.

Comment: The posted code: 1)  does not compile  2) indenting is not consistent 3) a 2D array would be better generated by: malloc(numRows) then in a loop: malloc(numColumns) 4) always check returned value from malloc() to assure operation was successful.  5) always check returned value from scanf() to assure operation was successful.

Comment: the question fails to meet the requirements of stackoverflow.  I.E. what was the expected output, what was the actual output, the posted code must compile/run for runtime problems.   Please correct the question or expect it to be closed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as loading that data in goes, there are lots of ways. One would be to make a `connectivity` struct, and dynamically allocate an array of those based on the number of edges value in the first line of the data file:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct connectivity {
    int source;
    int sink;
    int weight;
};

int main() {
    int num_verts = 0;
    int num_edges = 0;
    struct connectivity *edges = NULL;
    int i = 0;

    scanf("%d %d\n", &num_verts, &num_edges);

    edges = malloc(sizeof (struct connectivity) * num_edges);

    for (i = 0; i < num_edges; i++) {
        scanf("%d %d %d\n", &(edges[i].source), 
                            &(edges[i].sink),
                            &(edges[i].weight));
    }

    // use edges here

    free(edges);
}
```

Also, please use more legible variable names!

Comment: Nitpick, but how about `malloc(sizeof(*edges) * num_edges)` to please purists like myself? :P

Comment: Not when fed to the `sizeof` operator. Instead, it'll give you the size of the type `edges` is pointing to.

Answer (score 1):

From my experience, using an Edge struct will be very feasible to handle graph problems.

```
struct Edge{
    int to;
    int weight;
    Edge(int t, int w):to(t), weight(w){};
};
std::vector<vector<Edge> > graph;
int N,M; //no of vertices, edges
scanf("%d %d", &N,&M);
graph.resize(N);
int u, v, w;
for(int i = 0; i < M; i ++){
    scanf("%d %d %d", &u, &v, &w);
    graph[u].push_back(Edge(v, w));
}
```

Comment: This looks like C++, and the question is tagged C. Then again OP mentions "C/C++" in their question, so...